# Images from Simplepie feed?

Tags: php, html, rss, simplepie

I've installed Simplepie to syndicate blog posts from blog.domain.com to domain.com.  I'm custom-coding the actual feed items to give them individual styling, etc.

What I'm trying to do is create thumbnails to go in the feed.  My plan is to retrieve any images that exist inside the feed, pick the first one, and use it as the background image for a span element (thus parsing it down to a square aspect ratio).  However, I don't know how to do this.

Is there some sort of intra-post tag retrieval method?  I've tried a few things, which haven't rendered any immediate results, so I figured I'd ask here.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the namespace of the feed. I did something similar with Simplepie for a twitter module a while a ago and used something like:

```
foreach ($simplepie->get_items() as $item) {
  filter_xss($item->get_link(0, $rel = 'image'))
  ...
}
```

so you would need to see what attributes are in your feed items to search on. For reference, you can view the code in the module located [here](http://drupal.org/project/tweetsimple).